# How do you control which monitor the calibration occurs on

Tags: multiple-monitors, color-management, spyder

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 with a AMD Radeon HD 6570 video card with 4 DVI based monitors connected. I have a Datacolor Spyder X color calibration device. When I begin the process to calibrate one of my two HP primary/central monitors the box to place the Spyder appears on the far right monitor. I expected the box to appear on the monitor I was calibrating.

Is there some way to control which monitor gets the calibration area?

Is it as simple as making the monitor I want to calibrate the left most positioned monitor for the duration of the process?

Comment: I would apply security fixes asap if your details are correct; Ubuntu 22.04 hasn't reported itself as 22.04.1 since very early this year (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ shows the release of 22.04.2 but installed systems upgraded in the weeks before this) and an updated 22.04 system now reports itself as 22.04.3. Are you sure you're using Ubuntu 22.04.1? or just a Ubuntu based system?  (22.04.1 can be expected to be reported for upgraded 22.04 packages, but not as for a system release on a fully upgraded system)

Comment: I am fully patched. Sorry for that confusion. Uname -a reports:

Linux ---- 6.2.0-33-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 10:33:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: That detail (*in your last comment* show details about the Linux kernel; 6.2 being the HWE kernel for Ubuntu 22.04.3, 5.15 was the kernel for 22.04 & 22.04.1 & remains the kernel if using GA on 22.04.3, and the 22.04.1 in the kernel details you provided (`uname` etc) relate to packaging detail only; 22.04 showing initial release kernel, and 22.04.1 showing any updated kernel post-release, and **not** your running system level. Use `release` to view system details (`lsb_release -a` for all)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is my first venture into making Linux a fully operational desktop for daily use and not a utility OS. I'm learning as I go...  I just did a full reboot and "snap update", apt update", and "apt upgrade". All looks current the way I like it :). 

{
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
}